# Plot the result of Solve for multivalued solution

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I would like to plot the (most likely) multi-valued solution to an equation, as I vary one of the parameters. Here's my approach:

```
ClearAll[F, a, eq]
eq[f_, a_] := Exp[(1 - f)*0.5] == a* (1 - f)*0.5 + 1;
Solve[eq[f, 2], f]
Plot[Solve[eq[f, a], f], {a, 1, 10}]
```

This function is multi-valued for `a > 1`. However, the output of `Solve`  is of the form `{{f -> -1.51286}, {f -> 1.}}`, which apparently is something that `Plot` does not understand. How can I plot both values, for varying `a`, in the same graph?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is the argument for `Plot`.
Note:

```
eq[f_, a_] := Exp[(1 - f)*0.5] == a*(1 - f)*0.5 + 1;

Plot[f /. Solve[eq[f, a], f], {a, 1, 10}]
```

yields:

[image]

You can see the solutions:

```
fun[f_, a_] := Exp[(1 - f)*0.5] - a*(1 - f)*0.5 - 1;
Manipulate[
 Plot[fun[x, a], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-20, 100}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}], {a, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

`NSolve` finds (in this particular case and suppressing thrown errors with `Quiet`). In the following the dashed plot is a v root to show that `NSolve` is finding the roots other than 1.

```
sol[a_] := w /. First@NSolve[fun[w, a] == 0, w]
Manipulate[
 Quiet@Show[
   Plot[fun[x, a], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-20, 100}, 
    MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
    MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}],
   ParametricPlot[{sol[x], x}, {x, 1, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-20, 100}}, PlotStyle -> Dashed], 
   Graphics[{Red, Point[{s[a], a}]}], GridLines -> {{s[a]}, None}
   ], {a, 1, 10}]
```

[image]